# Getting errors using type alias

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component in which I have defined a type and used it in the code. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {withErrorBoundary} from '../../../../../ignitus-ErrorHandlingComponents/errorBoundary';
import * as S from '../styles';
import {AppIcon} from '../../../../../types/iconsTypes/iconEnums';

type Props = {
  name: AppIcon;
};


export const ProfileSideNavigation:React.FunctionComponent<Props> = withErrorBoundary( () => (
  <S.Container>
    <S.TopSection>
      <S.Avatar src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ignitus_assets/ig-avatars/eugene.png" alt="Profile-pic" />
      <S.ProfileDetailsContainer>
        <S.Name>Sophia Carter</S.Name>
        <S.Designation>Literature Student</S.Designation>
      </S.ProfileDetailsContainer>
    </S.TopSection>
    <S.BottomSection>
      <S.Icon name={AppIcon.BookmarkIcon} />
      <S.Progress>21 students and 11 professors are tracking progress</S.Progress>
    </S.BottomSection>
  </S.Container>
));
```

But it gives this error:

```
Type '{ name: AppIcon; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ClassAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & Pick<...> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ClassAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & Pick<...> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code. Just post the code samples.

Comment: Hi, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the wrapped component the way you do, you should separate the logic.

First, you define the `ProfileSideNavigation`, with the supplied props.

Next, you export the wrapped component.

This is how you can:

```
type Props = {
  name: AppIcon;
};    

export const ProfileSideNavigation: React.FC<Props> = () => (
  <S.Container>
    <S.TopSection>
      <S.Avatar src="https://storage.googleapis.com/ignitus_assets/ig-avatars/eugene.png" alt="Profile-pic" />
      <S.ProfileDetailsContainer>
        <S.Name>Sophia Carter</S.Name>
        <S.Designation>Literature Student</S.Designation>
      </S.ProfileDetailsContainer>
    </S.TopSection>
    <S.BottomSection>
      <S.Icon name={AppIcon.BookmarkIcon} />
      <S.Progress>21 students and 11 professors are tracking progress</S.Progress>
    </S.BottomSection>
  </S.Container>
));

export default withErrorBoundary(ProfileSideNavigation);
```